# JavaScript foreach an array and split them with commas and last one's comma with "and"

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I need to know how I can split an array with commas and if it's the last one element to the last one I have `, and`  and if it's the last one I add `.` to it. I have the following code. The output as one big string `honda, audi, tesla, and toyota.` the following is printing more than one. Also what if I wanted to push it one time into new array. So one big array of string `["honda, audi, tesla, and toyota."]`

```js
let namesArray = ["honda", "audi", "tesla", "toyota"];
let newOrder = ""
namesArray.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log(index);

  if (index === namesArray.length - 2) {
    newOrder = item + ' , and'
  } else if (index === namesArray.length - 1) {
    newOrder = (item + '.')
  } else {
    newOrder = (item + ',')
  }

})
console.log('new string ', newOrder)
```

`"new string ", "honda,audi,tesla,toyota."`

Comment: Add `"and "` and `"."` to the last element, then use `arr.join(", ")`

Comment: To fix your existing code you need to append to your existing string, not reassign, so use `newOrder += item + ...`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey when i do `newOrder.append(item + ' , and')` I get Uncaught TypeError: newOrder.append is not a function

Comment: ... Right. Look at my comment again. I didn't say "use `newOrder.append`. I said use `newOrder += ` instead of `newOrder =`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of what is wrong with your existing code, you are not *adding* the new string value to your output (i.e. use `newOrder +=`, not `newOrder =` in the loop):

```js
let namesArray = ["honda", "audi", "tesla", "toyota"];
let newOrder = ""
namesArray.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index === namesArray.length - 2) {
    newOrder += item + ', and '
  } else if (index === namesArray.length - 1) {
    newOrder += (item + '.')
  } else {
    newOrder += (item + ', ')
  }

})
console.log(newOrder)
```

It would be simpler though to just [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) a [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) of the array from the start to the second to last element, then add `, and` and the last element to that string:

```js
let namesArray=["honda", "audi", "tesla", "toyota"];

let newOrder = namesArray.slice(0,-1).join(', ') + ', and ' + namesArray.slice(-1) + '.';

console.log(newOrder)
```

Comment: what am I doing wrong. like what if I dont use slice and join. how come my for loop is not doing it

Comment: @blex it will work as long as the array has 2 or more elements, in this case it would produce `honda, and audi.`

Comment: in slice is -1 the last element?

Comment: OP should look at that as an index. `0` index starts just before `0`.... `-1` index is just before the last element. Indexes are always in front of their Array position.

Comment: @Metawaa negative numbers refer to "an offset from the end of the sequence". Since `start` is inclusive and `end` is exclusive, `slice(-1)` includes elements starting from the last element, while `slice(0,-1)` slices from the first element to the element before the last element.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const arr = ["honda", "audi", "tesla", "toyota"];

const result = arr
  .map((item, index) => {
    if (index === arr.length - 1) {
      return `and ${item}.`;
    } else {
      return `${item}, `;
    }
  })
  .join("");
console.log(result);
```

You can also use string template literal if the **array size in known prior**

```js
const arr = ["honda", "audi", "tesla", "toyota"];
const [a, b, c, d] = arr;
const result = `${a}, ${b}, ${c}, and ${d}.`;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function for reuse. First make a `.slice()` of your array, so the original is not affected. `.pop()` off the last Array element. Then `.join(', ')` and concatenate `+', and '` along with the element you popped off `+'.'`.

```js
function andIt(array){
  const a = array.slice(), p = a.pop()+'.';
  if(!a.length){
    return p;
  }
  return a.join(', ')+', and '+p;
}
const namesArray = ['honda', 'audi', 'tesla', 'toyota'];
console.log(andIt(namesArray)); console.log(andIt(['test']));
```